# Alert Dialog appears twice before starting a new intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-alertdialog, repeat

I am facing a behavior that seems to appear in many of my alert dialogs. The existing answers don't seem to address the behavior of my code. After clicking the yes button, a second similar alert dialog box pops up first before the intent is called.

```
public class MapsActivity extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);

        statusCheck();
        return view();
     }

    public void statusCheck() {
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();

        }
    }

      private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
        builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does `onCreateView` get called twice? Please show us your log(cat)...

Answer (score 0):

Seams that something missing, e.g: ...Builder(**view**.getContext()) where this view came from?

also

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);

    statusCheck();

   // MISSING: return the view here

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it weird to create another variable to .show()?
Try this

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
        builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }).show();
```

Comment: I've tried your method @toux toux but it still getting the same behavior.